# Avoid escaping \" to &quot; in tinyxml writing in C++

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I use tinyxml to write xml files.
For a tag I want to write `<tag>""</tag>`, but when I use following codes

```
TiXmlElement *tag=new TiXmlElement("tag");
TiXmlText *text=new TiXmlText("\"\"");
```

The content will be `<tag>&quot;&quot;</tag>`.
If I use

```
TiXmlText *text=new TiXmlText("");
```

The content will be `<tag/>`

How can I just write the quotes (") in xml?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why? Technically, double-quotes in XML should always be escaped to their ampersand entities.

Comment: @Dai This is to be compatible with another parser in a specific project.

Comment: BTW, if you can't find a solution, a workaround is to perform a regex-based find-and-replace operation to replace `&quot;` with `"` if it doesn't appear within two `"` symbols (e.g. in an attribute value).

Comment: Just out of curiosity, TinyXML2 introduced the `processEntities` argument for the [XMLDocument](http://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/classtinyxml2_1_1_x_m_l_document.html) class constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no update on this problem, the work-around to edit the generated xml files seems a doable approach, either by hand or with another program.